# What is the point in maintaining Developer 401 certification, when there is a transition exam to get AppBuilder and there is Platform Dev I&II

Tags: certification

I am not much sure about using "What is the point" or "Is it worth" :D Just curious that it will add some value till the day I pay for maintenance.

Previously 401 referred to the Force.com developer certification, Now for the developer role certifications there are two new certification programs are available Platform developer 1 and Platform developer 2.

And  with the available Dev401 there is a transition exam available to get App Builder Certification.

Will the Developer 401 continue to be available by maintaining all the release up-to-date or will that some day be discontinued(to even appear in our credentials).

Answer (score 1):

Next time when you have to pay for your dev maintenance, you will not be able to do so, this is the point where you have to decide to take the transition exam or not.

Be aware of that this is not dev related anymore, it is more admin as it is declarative.

for the dev route it is now the platform developer I, which in return is more like the former 1st part of the 501.

hope that hepls